# MySQL query rows with dates close to "today's" date

Tags: php, mysql, date, pdo

I'm trying to make a query in MySQL to return rows ranging from "yesterday" to some more days ahead.
My column format for dates is datetime, and my script is in PHP (using PDO).
I couldn't find or figure it out myself, It'll be a query to display the date and some more information from rows close to today's date from a certain category.

Is there a way to select dates like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mysql query can be something on the below lines -

```
select 
  * 
from 
  sample
where 
    dateCol >= DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL XX DAY))
and dateCol <= DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL YY DAY))
```

Comment: Hey! thanks! it worked, the code I used was the following:
`SELECT * FROM sampleWHERE dateCol >= DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AND cat = 'event' ORDER BY dateCol ASC LIMIT 8` (Just modified it to be more an example than my actual code)